# Laravel: How to separate array from query result into variables?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7, laravel-backpack

I have something like this:

```
return Model::get()->pluck('count','column');

Result:
{"ABC":1,"DEF":3,"GHI":1,"JKL":2}
```

How to separate the 'column' and 'count' into variables?

```
$column = ["ABC","DEF","GHI","JKL"];

$count = [1,3,1,2];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use native PHP functions; `array_keys` and `array_values`.

```
$result = Model::get()->pluck('count', 'column');
$column = array_keys($result);
$count = array_values($result);
```

For more details, read the below links;

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$array = Model::pluck('count','column')->toArray();
$key   = array_keys($array);
$values = array_values($array);
```